# scanf string and printf in C don't work as expected

Tags: c, string, printf, scanf

I'm working on an exercise for my university computer science course.

I've got to use multiple scanf and printf to get data about a book, data is stored in a struct.

The function that asks for data is

```
book_t addbook() {
    book_t book;

    printf("Insert ISBN: ");
    scanf("%s", book.isbn);

    printf("Insert author: ");
    scanf("%s", book.author);

    printf("Insert title: ");
    scanf("%s", book.title);

    printf("Insert year: ");
    scanf("%d", &book.year);

    printf("Insert shelf: ");
    scanf("%d", &book.shelf);

    printf("Insert price: ");
    scanf("%lf", &book.price);

    return book;
}
```

But when I run the program, on the console I got this:

```
Insert ISBN: 978-88-08-06485-1
Insert author: Author Name
Insert title: Insert year:
```

I wrote the ISBN and pressed return, I wrote Author Name and pressed return, and I got the next two printf, how is that possible?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Next time before ask try to put some printf and dump some trace. You will teach more than ask and read the answer.

Comment: I really think `fgets` is usually a much better option than `scanf` for line-oriented input.

Comment: `scanf("%s", book.author);` --> `scanf(" %[^\n]", book.author);`

Comment: If using scanf then the issue of buffer size rears its ugly head, which is a pain to deal with (there's no easy way to scanf into the size of buffer you have and then discard excess characters, if any)

Answer (score 2):

Probably when you provided the Author Name you provided its full name (first + last name). The C parsed the Author name only as the first name and since the buffer had another string it was used for the title name so you were not asked for another string for it.

A repro is below:

[image]

In this example, the author is set to "Jon" and the title is set to Doe:

[image]

Comment: And a solution? Use one-name authors only? ("Madonna" wrote a book dint she?)

Answer (score 0):

scanf reads until it finds a whitespace character. In your case:

```
ISBN: blabla -> scanf reads blabla
Author: Author Name -> scanf reads Author
title: -> scanf has already Name in buffer, so Name is set into title immediatly
year: -> input next.
```

So the input for title is skipped because scanf already has a buffered value